# Empty Web Application for .Net 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I want to create an empty web application for .Net 4.0 in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web. I can't find out how I can do that? If I create a .Net 4.5 project, I can select an empty one. But that option doesn't exists for .Net 4.0. Is it possible to create an empty web application for .Net 4.0?

Or I can create a regular web forms application with tons of unwanted stuff. If I'll delete all files (except Properties,References and Web.config), is it OK? Of course I'll keep web.config, but it has lots of unwanted informations too. How can I edit it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The templates from Visual Studio 12 still works under 2013.

See : http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#vs2012

In "New Projects" you can click the Visual Studio 2012 under Web to Select Empty Web Application. If you don't have the templates you can probable add/download them (I don't have a URL though).

[image]